# TypeError: Object of type 'LabelEncoder' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, model, pickle

I was trying to upload my model training results to json file using json.dumps method, but it seems to be failing with the below error

```
TypeError: Object of type 'LabelEncoder' is not JSON serializable
```

My code looks something like this:

```
my_dict = {'a': LabelEncoder(), 'b': LabelEncoder(), 'c': LabelEncoder(), 'd': LabelEncoder()}
json.dumps(my_dict, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
```

PS: Previously, I was using pickle files to do the above operation but pickle files has Python version dependency in which it was created and hence using json for removing pickle dependency.

I tried many things found across internet but it's not helping!

Answer (score 0):

Only certain data types can be converted to JSON, and `LabelEncoder` is not one of them. You can extract the parameters using the `classes_` attribute and convert them to `dict`:

```py
keys_a = LabelEncoder_a.classes_
values_a = encode.transform(keys_a)
encoder_a_params = dict(zip(keys_a, values_a))

...
encoder_b_params = ...

my_dict = {'a': encoder_a_params, 'b': encoder_b_params , ...}
json_str = json.dumps(my_dict, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
```

Comment: Hi @jurel,
When used LabelEncoder_a.classes_, LabelEncoder_a is not defined error is popping.

Comment: It is a generic variable name I used to represent a LabelEncoder object already fitted to a dataset. Feel free to replace with the corresponding variable in your code

Comment: I'm replacing 'a' with my variable name in the code, it's the same error. Currently I'm testing in Jupyter notebook with custom defined my_dict to check whether the change works.

Comment: You should replace LabelEncoder_a, LabelEncoder_b, etc. with names of the variables that contain fitted LabelEncoder object, and for each one, repeat the first three lines of code snippet, maybe with different names such as keys_b, values_b, encoder_b_params, etc.

Comment: Hi @msamsami I'm getting this error now,
AttributeError: 'LabelEncoder' object has no attribute 'encode'. Just FYI here a,b,c in my_dict are the categorical variable names in my dataset.